# Customized Catch-A-Ride

Tags: borderlands-2

Is there a way to save the settings on any of the Catch-A-Ride stations?

I prefer using the rocket launcher as opposed to the machine gun, is there a way to have the Catch-A-Ride station to default Vehicle 1 to be the machine gun option and Vehicle 2 to be the rocket launcher? The interface screen itself is pretty basic and I see no option for it right now. Is there a feature to unlock the ability to save it later on?

Is there a way to always apply the same skin to the vehicles as well?

Comment: I'd like that, too, but AFAIK there's no way :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>Gearbox may address this in a later update.</del>

It's finally here!

> - August 29th
> - Saved the player's vehicle skin choice so that it doesn't have to be re-chosen in each new play session.

Source: [BL2 official patch notes](http://support.gearboxsoftware.com/entries/22147216-Xbox-360-Update-Hot-Fix-Information)